# Can the default gem installation directory be user configured?

Tags: origen-sdk

In the [origen docs](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/starting/gems/#Importing_Gems) it says that the gems are installed in the user's home directory.  Can this be configured by each user?

- EDIT *

I placed a copy of the origen_site_config.yml file in my application's root directory and enabled the following line:

```
# Define where a typical user's home directory will be, with a hidden directory for Origen.
home_dir: /users/thisuser/origen
```

I expected this to work and start installing at /users/thisuser/origen/.origen but it did not.  I deleted the .bundle and lbin directories and got no change in the installation directory either.

thx

Answer (score 1):

This question prompted a PR and some [new documentation](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/starting/workspace/#Workspace_Size_Considerations) on how to change the install directory of gems within Origen.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever tried it but you should be able to override the install using the [site_config](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/blob/e06d3cc0b6776d1d41900c7f8d24c5497fb07363/origen_site_config.yml#L27).

Comment: thanks rlaj.  I edited that file and placed it in the working directory of my app and it didn't change the install location.  I removed the ~/.origen directory and did a bundle install and it still went to the same home directory instead of my new path.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby/Bundler will by default install gems into the Ruby installation directory.

However, since it is commonplace in corporate engineering compute environments for users to share a common Ruby installation to which they don't have write access, Origen provides a default Bundler configuration which will instead install gems to the user's home directory.

This install location is defined by the `gem_install_dir` attribute of the [Origen Site Config](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/starting/company/).

This can be overridden on a company level in the master site config, however this is (currently at least) a static variable, so the only way to make it user specific is to reference `$HOME` or some similar Linux-level variable used within the given environment.

It is possible to have all users share a gem installation directory, however the downside to that is that all users will need to have write access to it and therefore potentially a hack to a gem source by one user could end up introducing a very hard to detect bug that affects the whole company.

Better then, is to override on a per-user basis if you don't like filling up your home directory with gem files.

Here are the various ways to do that:

1) Any site config variable can be overridden by setting an environment variable named `ORIGEN_<uppercased variable name>`, so `ORIGEN_GEM_INSTALL_DIR` in this case.

2) Symlink `$HOME/.origen` to somewhere else.

3) Users can use their own site config file. [See the guide](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/starting/company/) for more details, but Origen will search multiple places for a config and parameters defined in configs which are closest to where the application lives will override more distant defaults. So for example, say a user kept all of their Origen workspaces in `/my_projects/origen/`, e.g. `/my_projects/origen/my_app`, then anything config attributes defined in `/my_projects/origen/origen_site_config.yml` would override those set at the company-level.

Bundler will cache this configuration on a per-workspace basis, so anytime you make changes to a configuration like this it is recommended to either start with a fresh workspace, or run the [fix_my_workspace](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/starting/workspace/) script.